# How Spring MVC resolve subclass injection

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to understand how Spring MVC resolve subclass injection while autowiring.

For Example:

```
class Person
{
      @autowired    
      private Customer cust;
}

interface Customer{}

class Customer1 implements Customer{}

class Customer2 implements Customer{}
```

Now how will spring know which class to inject in Person.

Please excuse if this is a duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the *@Autowired* on property it will use the autowire [byType](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/) to resolve the collaborating bean. So in the case as you've described it will produce a conflict of more than one qualifying bean.

To resolve this, you should use [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation, and name you're bean by using *@Component*, or some other appropriate annotation stereotype

```
class Person
{
      @Qualifier("customer1")
      @Autowired    
      private Customer cust;
}

interface Customer{}

@Component("customer1")
class Customer1 implements Customer{}

@Component("customer2")
class Customer2 implements Customer{}
```